# How to set value to IdentityOptions from Controller(not from StartUp.cs)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to call below properties from controller,as i wanted to apply these validations only for the user creating from that controller.

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>{
options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;});
```

Is their a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is configured once at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Options pattern` to get `IdentityOptions` in the controller like the following:

```
private IdentityOptions _op;

public HomeController(IOptions<IdentityOptions> op)
{
   _op = op.Value;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
   //Example.
   _op.Password.RequireDigit = false;

   return View();
}
```

For more information, read [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.0)